# How to improve SQL query when conditions grows dynamically

Tags: sql

**Usecase:**
User want to get Sum amount by grouping a certain number of column values. To restrict the number of rows the Where condition is provided with the columns with their respective values.

**Query Description:**

Below is the SQL query in which the columns are decided dynamically as per the user requirement and at the same time the Groupby columns are also decided by the user dynamically.

In the Where condition, the condition grows dynamically depending upon the user selection.

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT transactionLine.department,
       transactionLine.class,
       transactionLine.cseg1,
       transactionLine.cseg_grant,
       transactionLine.cseg_restriction,
       transactionLine.cseg_revtype,
       transactionLine.cseg_rev_sub,
       transactionLine.cseg_timerestrict,
       transactionLine.cseg_fun_exp,
       transactionLine.cseg_region,
       BUILTIN_RESULT.TYPE_FLOAT(SUM(((NVL(CASE
                                               WHEN transaction.posting = 'T' THEN TO_NUMBER(transactionaccountingLine.amount)
                                           END, 0) + NVL(CASE
                                                             WHEN transaction.recordType = 'purchaseorder' THEN TO_NUMBER(transactionaccountingLine.amount)
                                                         END, 0)) - NVL(CASE
                                                                            WHEN ((transaction.recordType = 'vendorbill'
                                                                                   AND BUILTIN.DF(transactionLine.createdfrom) IS NOT NULL)
                                                                                  AND UPPER(BUILTIN.DF(transaction_0.status)) NOT LIKE '%CLOSED%')
                                                                                 AND UPPER(BUILTIN.DF(transaction_0.status)) NOT LIKE '%FULLY BILLED%' THEN TO_NUMBER(transactionaccountingLine.amount)
                                                                        END, 0)) + NVL(CASE
                                                                                           WHEN (transaction.recordType = 'vendorbill'
                                                                                                 AND transaction.posting = 'F')
                                                                                                AND BUILTIN.DF(transactionLine.createdfrom) IS NOT NULL THEN TO_NUMBER(transactionaccountingLine.amount)
                                                                                       END, 0))) AS SUMNVLCASEWHENposting
FROM TRANSACTION,
     account,
     transactionaccountingLine,
     TRANSACTION transaction_0,
                 transactionLine
WHERE ((((transactionaccountingLine.account = account.id(+)
          AND (transactionLine.transaction = transactionaccountingLine.transaction
               AND transactionLine.id = transactionaccountingLine.transactionline))
         AND transactionLine.createdfrom = transaction_0.id(+))
        AND transaction.id = transactionLine.transaction))
  AND ((transactionLine.department= '11' 
  AND transactionLine.cseg_grant  ='1'
  AND transactionLine.class = '12' 
  AND transactionLine.cseg_restriction = '1'
  AND transactionLine.cseg_revtype = '1'
  AND transactionLine.cseg1 = '4' 
  AND transactionLine.cseg_rev_sub = '1'
  AND transactionLine.cseg_timerestrict = '1'
  AND transactionLine.cseg_fun_exp = '4'
  AND transactionLine.cseg_region = '1') OR (transactionLine.department= '12' 
  AND transactionLine.cseg_grant  ='1'
  AND transactionLine.class = '12' 
  AND transactionLine.cseg_restriction = '1'
  AND transactionLine.cseg_revtype = '1'
  AND transactionLine.cseg1 = '4' 
  AND transactionLine.cseg_rev_sub = '1'
  AND transactionLine.cseg_timerestrict = '1'
  AND transactionLine.cseg_fun_exp = '4'
  AND transactionLine.cseg_region = '1'))
  AND ((NVL(account.custrecord_bm_budgetaccount, 'F') = 'F'
        AND (NOT(UPPER(transaction.status) IN ('PURCHORD:H', 'PURCHORD:G', 'PURCHORD:A', 'PURCHORD:P'))
             OR UPPER(transaction.status) IS NULL)
        AND UPPER(account.accttype) IN ('COGS',
                                        'DEFEREXPENSE',
                                        'EXPENSE',
                                        'OTHEXPENSE')))
GROUP BY transactionLine.class,
         transactionLine.department,
         transactionLine.cseg_grant,
         transactionLine.cseg_restriction,
         transactionLine.cseg_revtype,
         transactionLine.cseg1,
         transactionLine.cseg_rev_sub,
         transactionLine.cseg_timerestrict,
         transactionLine.cseg_fun_exp,
         transactionLine.cseg_region
```

**Question:**

- Is there any performance impact if the query has more no of `Group by`
  conditions?
- Here in this example, the result return from the query is limited by having the below `where` conditions. This query can grow as user select different values for the respective column. By doing this way is there going to be any performance impact? Can this query be fine-tuned to improve the query performance?

```
    ((transactionLine.department= '11' 
          AND transactionLine.cseg_grant  ='1'
          AND transactionLine.class = '12' 
          AND transactionLine.cseg_restriction = '1'
          AND transactionLine.cseg_revtype = '1'
          AND transactionLine.cseg1 = '4' 
          AND transactionLine.cseg_rev_sub = '1'
          AND transactionLine.cseg_timerestrict = '1'
          AND transactionLine.cseg_fun_exp = '4'
          AND transactionLine.cseg_region = '1') OR (transactionLine.department= '12' 
          AND transactionLine.cseg_grant  ='1'
          AND transactionLine.class = '12' 
          AND transactionLine.cseg_restriction = '1'
          AND transactionLine.cseg_revtype = '1'
          AND transactionLine.cseg1 = '4' 
          AND transactionLine.cseg_rev_sub = '1'
          AND transactionLine.cseg_timerestrict = '1'
          AND transactionLine.cseg_fun_exp = '4'
          AND transactionLine.cseg_region = '1'))
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: For performance questions you need to provide an execution plan using "Paste The Plan"

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged